# Подскажите как можно автоматизировать импорт текстов из уточненных интернет ресурсов и "анализировать" текст на предмет ключевых слов?

Tags: python

Подскажите как можно автоматизировать импорт текстов из уточненных интернет ресурсов и "анализировать" текст на предмет ключевых слов? Возможно ли это (желательно в python, но устроит любой другой язык)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от вида ресурсов, какие данные Вам надо получать из этих ресурсов, и какого рода анализ надо делать.

Если это именно тексты, а не html страницы которые надо парсить,  то для импорта подойдет пакет из стандартной библиотеки [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). Если надо парсить html, то Вам нужна библиотека [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Для простого поиска слов в тексте можно использовать строковый метод [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find). Для более сложного стандартный модуль [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Для более более сложного анализа - [библиотеку NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) для обработки естественного языка.